# Keep getting permission denied or unauthorized request

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database, agk-basic

I using Appgamekit studio with the built in http commands. With these commands i was able to signup users and login, with open rules i cconnect to the database to post and read. Once i added rules. it keeps telling permission denied or unauthorized request. I havent got any confirmation emails ethier so i wonder it its n even confirmed? But imso having trouble sending the verification email. Everything im  g im using http request from in app

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$uid":{
      ".read":"$uid === auth.uid",
      ".write":"$uid === auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

sample code:

```
function senddatabase()
local result$ as string
local idtoken as string
IHTTP = CreateHTTPConnection()
SetHTTPHost(IHTTP, realtdata, 1)//realtdata = next-species-29059882-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com
AddHTTPHeader( iHTTP,'Content-Type: application/json','set')
//send file to database
useridtoken.idToken = userdata.localid
//useridtoken.idToken = userdata.idToken
result$ = 
SendHTTPRequest(IHTTP,'data.json?auth='+userdata.uid,userdata.tojson())
while GetHTTPResponseReady( iHTTP ) = 0
print("connecting.....")
endwhile
response$ = GetHTTPResponse( iHTTP )
statuscode = GetHTTPStatusCode( iHTTP )
CloseHTTPConnection( iHTTP )
rawdata = result$
endfunction result$
```

Tried many variations of adding different headers and different uid and idtokens with no luck. Im very new to using the rest methods and also using them in appgamekit studio.

ive used posman with this ul and it still doesnt work https://next-species-29059882-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/data.json?auth=s4hmxQDqFNbDPd13ioxaYzKJUbn1

Comment: How to authenticate a REST request to the Firebase Realtime Database is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#authenticate_with_an_id_token. So you'll need to add an `auth` parameter to the URL with the ID token of the signed in user.

Comment: thank you but i have read the doc and fallowed it but the best i was able to get was permission denied. in my rules playground it works if i click authorized and get the firebase uid and place it before the data like default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/<uid>/data

Comment: As far as I can tell from the code you shared you are not passing an `auth` parameter in the URL, which is what the doc I linked shows to do.

Comment: SetHTTPHost(IHTTP, realtdatabase, 1)//#constant realtdatabase = "next-species-29059882-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com"
AddHTTPHeader( iHTTP,'Content-Type: application/json','set')
  // userdata.uid = firebase uid
 result$ = SendHTTPRequest(IHTTP,'data.json?auth='+userdata.uid,userdata.tojson())

Comment: Update the code in the question please. But note that `userdata.uid` is **not** the same as passing the ID token, and *that* is what the API requires.

Comment: Even if ive defined userdata.uid as the user id token? I would also like clarification if its the uid that shows up next to their email in the auth list because i get a return data of a localid that is the same as the uid, idtoken and a refresh token